# purrr: How to pluck a list element's contents (instead of the element)

Tags: r, purrr

In cases where I have a list of tibbles, I sometimes `purrr::keep()` multiple elements and then combine using `reduce()` to end up with a tibble, however when I `purrr::pluck()` or `purrr::keep()` only one, doing a reduce doesn't make sense.  What is the best way to get at the tibble, rather than the list element containing the tibble?

I've found that doing `keep() %>% enframe() %>% unnest()` works in some cases but not others, but it seems messy regardless.

Other attemps:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
mylist <- lst(cars, diamonds)

mylist %>% pluck("cars") %>% typeof
#> [1] "list"

mylist %>% pluck("cars") %>% as.tibble() %>% typeof
#> [1] "list"

mylist %>% pluck("cars")[1]
#> Error in .[pluck("cars"), 1]: incorrect number of dimensions

mylist %>% pluck("cars")[[1]]
#> Error in .[[pluck("cars"), 1]]: incorrect number of subscripts

mylist %>% pluck("cars") %>% unlist() %>% typeof
#> [1] "double"

mylist %>% pluck("cars") %>% unnest() %>% typeof
#> [1] "list"

mylist %>% pluck("cars") %>% flatten %>% typeof
#> [1] "list"
```

Created on 2018-03-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

The goal is to get the tibble.

Comment: Consider `tibble::is_tibble()` or `base::is.data.frame()` instead of `typeof()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nothing like doing a bunch of reprex to solve your own (stupid) question!

Here's the deal for anyone else:

1) all tibbles will return "list" from `typeof()` (this is what threw me off)

2) `keep` is for multiple elements.  Thus to get to a tibble, you'll have to do some kind of reduction (`bind_rows`, `left_join`, etc).

3) `pluck` is for single elements, and will return the element contents.

I stole this example from Hadley and updated with `purrr` functions:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to make an addition to your solution. If you're trying to pluck out a data frame/tibble, pull doesn't work since it only takes a single column. I ran into this when trying to pluck out a single tibble from a list-column whose tibbles were nested in another tibble. The following will work: df_withlc %>% filter(row_number == 1) %>% pluck('lc_name') %>% map_df(.f = as_tibble). The filter is only used to get a single row. as_tibble expects a data frame rather than a data frame in a list, so you need to wrap it in map_df so that it gets the expected input.